# How to extend GHC's Thread State Object

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, ghc, c-minus-minus

I'd like to add two extra fields of type `StgWord32` to the *thread state object* (TSO). Based on the information I found on the GHC-Wiki and from looking at the source code, I have extended the struct in `/includes/rts/storage/TSO.h` and changed the program that creates different offsets (creating `DerivedConstants.h`). The compiler, the rts, and a simple application re-compile, but at the end of the execution (in `hs_exit_`) the garbage collector complains:

```
 internal error: scavenge_stack: weird activation record found on stack: 45
```

I guess it has to to with `cmm` and/or the STG implementation details (the offsets are generated since the structs are not visible at `cmm` level, correct me if I'm wrong). Is the order of fields significant? Have I missed a file that should be changed?

I use a *debug* build of the compiler and RTS and a rather dated *ghc 6.12.3* on a 64bit architecture. Any hints to relevant documentation and comments
on the difference between ghc 6 and 7 regarding TSO handling are welcome, too.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a different, simpler way.

Comment: I want to carry around some extra information with each thread to record for instance the ids of parent threads and use it when making load balancing decisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that turned out good enough for me was to introduce a separate data structure for each `Capability` that would hold the additional information for each lightweight thread. I have used a `HashTable` (see `rts/Hash.h` and `.c`) mapping from thread id to the custom info struct. The entries were added when the threads were created from sparks (in `schduleActiveteSpark`).

Timing the creation, insertion, lookup and destruction of the entries and the table showed negligible overhead for small programs. The main overhead results from the actual usage of the information and should ideally be kept outside of the innermost scheduler loop. For the `THREADED_RTS` build one needs to ensure that other Capabilities don't access tables that are not their own (or use a `mutex` if such access is required, which is potential source of additional overhead).

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are getting comes from: `ghc/rts/sm/Scav.c`.  Specifically at line 1917:

```
 default:
    barf("scavenge_stack: weird activation record found on stack: %d", (int)(info->i.type));
```

It looks like you need to also modify `ClosureTypes.h`, which you can find in `ghc/includes/rts/storage`.  This file seems to contain the different kinds of headers that can appear in a heap object.  I've also run into some strange bootstrapping errors, where if I try to rebuild using the stage-1 compiler, I get the error you mentioned, but if I do a clean build, then it compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I  wonder why do you think I should introduce a new closure type? I'd like to keep the standard TSO closure type but add a field to the TSO object. To me it looks like some offsets are wrong an the info field get overwritten by accident.

Comment: On second thought, you probably don't need to create a new heap object, especially if the new field you are adding isn't a pointer.  Did you try doing a clean build?  That has solved this problem for me in the past.

Comment: unfortunately a clean build didn't help (I can't assume to have working stage-2 compiler either)